# Ошибка рендеринга Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml, render, android-constraintlayout

Учусь работать с `Constraint Layout` все `Layout` в своих приложениях начал менять на `Constraint Layout` и делать под них разметку. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой как ошибка рендеринга при просмотре макета в **Android Studio.**

Вот стек ошибки:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1370.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:369)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:93)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:88)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:209)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:127)
    ... 30 more
```

и еще одна ошибка под названием `String index out of range -1`

Вот мой макет один из двух не рабочих

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".activity.SignInActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header">
            <EditText
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_check_email"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:id="@+id/img_check_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/check"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/email"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_card">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_visibility_password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                android:autofillHints="" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_visibility_password"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:src="@drawable/eye_off"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/check_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_card">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_remember"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/text"
            android:text="@string/remember_me"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_forgot_password"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_forgot_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:text="@string/forgot_password"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_button"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/check_layout" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/or"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_sign_in">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_or"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:background="@color/text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@id/view_or"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/background"
            android:background="@drawable/backor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/or"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/social"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/or">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_facebook"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_google_plus"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/google_plus"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_facebook"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_twitter"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_google_plus"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/go_to_register"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_create_new"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:text="@string/create_new"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот такая вот ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вся эта проблема появилась только после перезагрузки пк до этого такого не было.
Читал ответы в разных вопросах на разных форумах и вот что я уже делал что бы убрать эту проблему:

1. Перезагружал и комп и студию
2. Удалял кеш
3. Строил читый проект
4. Стирал и начинал писать макет заново ( но только констрейнтов стает больше 3 или 4 снова выбивает ошибку)
5. Менял API и устройство для вывода рендера
6. Менял тему
7. Переворачивал экран

Жду вашых предложений или хотя бы объяснений

Кстати макеты рабочие и на эмуляторе они все коректно отображают

и еще вот как отображалось оно раньше
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Комп у меня не слабый, по крайней мере я так считаю
Intel Core i5 9400f
Gigabyte 1660 ti 6GB
16 Gb
512 SSD (Студия тут)
2 TB Hdd
Экран 2К

**ОТВЕТ ДАН В ШЕСТИ ПЕРВЫХ КОММЕНТАРИЯХ** pavlofff

Comment: Прежде чем вы продолжите учится работать с ConstraintLayout, хотелось бы вам рассказать, что необходимость в этом  контейнере появилась именно из за того, чтобы убрать вложенность одного контейнера в другой. Дело в том, что такая вложенность отнимала очень много ресурсов. Решая эту проблему, Google постарались и сделали действительно мощный инструмент, который имеет все возможные способы позиционирования виджетов, чтобы вам не пришлось вкладывать контейнеры друг в друга и у них это получилось.

Comment: И вот теперь, собрав разметку из вопроса, вы просто плюнули прямо в лицо тому немногому доброму и вечному, что еще осталось в "корпорации добра". В общем, прежде чем решать вашу проблему, вы должны знать, что при правильном использовании данного контейнера она не появится и надо ли продолжать тратить время на ее решение или все же лучше научится использовать этот контейнер так, как задумано разработчиками изначально.

Comment: Возможно вам будет легче научится правильно использовать этот контейнер, посмотрев анимированную презентацию по возможностям и правилам верстки в нем, которую сделала Google: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/constraint-layout#0 . Они редко делают что то подобное, наверное это действительно важно. Как вы сможете сами заметить, вся верстка одноуровневая, нигде нет никакой иерархии одного контейнера в другом.

Comment: С момента написания этой презентации прошло некоторое время и в контейнер добавили еще немало возможностей, как например позиционирование виджетов под определенным углом и для полноценного использования этого замечательного инструмента крайне рекомендуется изучить актуальную документацию https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout

Comment: Так же хотелось бы обратить внимание, что у  ConstraintLayout нет аттрибутов: orientation, layout_gravity, gravity, layout_below, layout_weight. Трудно предположить, на что вы рассчитываете, используя их с этим контейнером, но они там не работают.

Comment: Если вам нужен фон-подложка под несколько виджетов, то можно использовать просто View, указав для него фон, другие виджеты которые должны быть на этом  фоне спозиционировать от краев этого View и расположить поверх него, ConstraintLayout позволяет накладывать виджеты друг на друга.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за ответ. Вы ответили на все мои вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалил все Constraint layout кроме КОРНЕВОГО и проблема пропала вот XML код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".activity.SignUpActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/account"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_check_account"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_check_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_card"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/check"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_check_email"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_check_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_card"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/check"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_check_account"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_visibility_password_top"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_visibility_password_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_card"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eye_off"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_check_email"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_visibility_password_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.01"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_top"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_visibility_password_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_card"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eye_off"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_visibility_password_top"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_remember"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/button"
        android:buttonTint="@color/text"
        android:drawable="@drawable/check"
        android:text="@string/privacy"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/privacy_policy"
        android:textColor="@color/button"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cb_remember"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_visibility_password_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.078" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:text="@string/and"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.174" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="212dp"
        android:text="@string/term_of_service"
        android:textColor="@color/button"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_button"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/go_to_login"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_create_new"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_sign_up"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.903" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_create_new"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_sign_up"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.903" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```